# What a simple get; set; in a class means?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

Take for example following code from a class:

```
public class Employee : IEntity
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
}

public class Company : IEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string TaxID { get; set }
}
```

I always used get; and set; with something in braces. I never left them like this.

Writing just:

get; set;

What it means?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this mean ? public Name {get; set;}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310223/what-does-this-mean-public-name-get-set)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Auto-Implemented Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)

> In C# 3.0 and later, auto-implemented
>   properties make property-declaration
>   more concise when no additional logic
>   is required in the property accessors.
>   They also enable client code to create
>   objects. When you declare a property
>   as shown in the following example, the
>   compiler creates a private, anonymous
>   backing field that can only be
>   accessed through the property's get
>   and set accessors.

Answer (score 3):

These are called Auto-Implemented Properties:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx

The compiler will generate a backing field, similar to this code:

```
public class Company : IEntity
{
    public string Name
    {
      get { return _Name; }
      set { _Name = value; }
    }
    private string _Name;
}
```

It was decided that this syntax could be made much shorter, but still keep all the same utility, hence Auto-Implemented Properties were born :)

Comment: I think this is the first answer that really cleared my doubt. Glad to know that it was decided later to shorten the code, otherwise I was messed up with the two variants of code.

Answer (score 1):

Just look at it as an quick and easy C# way of giving you a read write permission over a variable.

One of the good things of C# if you ask me.

The other answers pretty much tell you everything else there is to know about auto get set.
Even though these two quotes seem somewhat conflicting:

CD said:

> In C# 3.0 and later, auto-implemented
>   properties make property-declaration
>   more concise **when no additional logic
>   is required** in the property accessors.
>   They also enable client code to create
>   objects. When you declare a property
>   as shown in the following example, the
>   compiler creates a private, anonymous
>   backing field that can only be
>   accessed through the property's get
>   and set accessors.

While Merlyn Morgan-Graham said:

> These are called Auto-Implemented
>   Properties:
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx
>
> The compiler will generate a backing
>   field, similar to this code:

```
public class Company : IEntity {
    public string Name
    {
      get { return _Name; }
      set { _Name = value; }
    }
    private string _Name; }
```

> It was decided that this syntax could
>   be made much shorter, **but still keep
>   all the same utility**, hence
>   Auto-Implemented Properties were born
>   :)

To me that seems like CD said it does create a condition whilst Merlyn Morgan-Graham said there are none.

I think CD is correct when stating you can longer use , for example, the setters write permission as a response to also change whatever it's writing.

```
private int x = 3;

public int _x { get; set /*Change x*/; }
```

You would have to use the normal get set construction for that