# C# syntax Where is the data

Tags: c#, c++

```
 public class DeviceInformation
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> m_parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public string Class { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

    public DeviceUID UID { get; set; }

    public IDictionary<string, string> Parameters 
    {
        get { return m_parameters; }
    }
}
```

The class does not even define private data such as Class, Model, SerialNumber. What are the accessor function for?  I am a c++ user and really confused by this syntax.

Comment: Related question:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/4662442/3063706

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler creates a private variable and makes the getter and setter for you.

Answer (score 0):

Those are what we call in the C# world 'Properties' while you -can- use them as accessors for existing private or public data members, as you have them they exist as full fledged data members.